# Codeigniter can not delete record

Tags: php, codeigniter

i trying to use codeigniter on my web, i don't know why but i can not delete user from my datase, i think i made a mistake on my code, but i can not find it. can you have a look and help me solve this problem.
This is my controller code:

```
    function user_delete($id_user){
    $this->load->model('membership_model');
    if ($this->membership_model->isAdmin())
    {
        $this->membership_model->deleteUser();
        redirect('/site/admins_area');
    }else
        $this->load->view('not_logged_in_view');
}
```

And this is my model code:

```
function deleteUser(){
    $this->db->where('id_user', $this->uri->segment(3));
    $this->db->delete('user');
}
```

In my view code, when admin click on delete it will guide them to controller like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Delete</button></center>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
    </div>
<div class="modal-body">
      <p>Do you want to delete it?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>site/user_delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" role="button">Delete</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Can you help?

Comment: where pass $id_user in call user_delete() in your controller ?

Comment: i have not got your point yet. What do you mean please?

Comment: where are you pass $id_user variable to this user_delete() function ?

Comment: it comes from my view

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $ud->id_user; ?>">`

Comment: are you able to get that variable from view ?

Comment: '<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>site/user_delete/<?php echo $user_id ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" role="button">Delete</a>'

here please send an $id_user

Comment: `<?php echo base_url();?>site/user_delete/12`
Your url should be like this

Comment: @santosh i think may be that is the problem, but i edit my code as you say  but it has an error, undefine valuable $id_user

Comment: Have you tried using a `<form> some form content</form>` on modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a problem with the link

```
 <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>site/user_delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" role="button">Delete</a>
```

Use this one:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('site/user_delete');?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" role="button">Delete</a>
```

If error persist. Please provide the error.

Comment: it has an error said : use of undifined constant user_delete assumed as user_delete

Comment: so, site is the name of your controller? just confirming things.

Comment: yep my cotroller is site.
and i did edit like you said but it has an error undefine valuable userid

Comment: Putting the url inside base_url will have no difference here. It's just for better syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Your Controller

```
$this->membership_model->deleteUser($id_user);
```

On Your Model

```
function deleteUser($id_user){
   $this->db->where('id_user', $id_user);
    $this->db->delete('user');
}
```

Comment: could you please print $id_user

Comment: can not echo $id_user, 
Missing argument 1 for Site::user_delete()
that is the error, can you help

Comment: You are not sending any agrument on the url 

try url like user_delete/2  // 2 is an user_id

Comment: how can i fix that, can you?

Comment: in your view 
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>site/user_delete/<?php echo $user_id; ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" role="button">Delete</a>

 $user_id is a userid which you are going to delete

Comment: i did as you said, now i can recieve the $id_user but when i click on delete, it has an error page not found. why is that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101360/discussion-between-santosh-and-hoang-trung-hiu).

Comment: you can send value of that user from controller
in that page you must have a User Details with user id
print that user id there

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working, it's just that perhaps you arent linking your routes correctly. You are trying to delete on URL segment, there is no segment 3 as ID.

In order to have the correct URL for this query your URL should look like:

```
 echo base_url('site/user_delete/'.$user_id);
```

Assuming you already know how to parse variables to a view, this shouldnt be difficult. Also note, you will need to change your current route which looks likes follow:

```
 $route['site/user_delete']  = "controllername/function";
```

to

```
  $route['site/user_delete/(:num)' = "controllername/function/$1";
```

This will allow parameters to be send over the URL. Along with that you will need to change your model aswell to accept a parameter instead of direct segment.